# Alternatives to DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have some data that I am currently implementing the presentation of in a `Windows.Forms.DataGridView`. I am questioning if DataGridView is the best component to use and if not, what component is.

The image below shows how the data is to be presented. The first 2 columns are static. The 3rd column is data entered by the user. The reason I think that DataGridView may not be appropriate is that there a 2 kinds of rows. The first kind has a Group and nothing in the Item and Grower columns. The second kind has nothing in Group, always has an Item, and may or may not have a Grower.

Is DataGridView the best component for this? If so, how would a `BindingSource` be defined?

[image: DataGridView]

Comment: Try taking a look at this question, its related but since you are asking about a specific implementation I don't really consider it a duplicate, could still be helpful in your search though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493003/what-are-the-alternatives-to-datagridview

Comment: I think GridView is fine with Merge cells: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774966/how-to-merge-datagridview-cell-in-winforms

Comment: @RH6: I had seen this (probably should have mentioned that in the question). Not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Mohit: that may help, thanks.

Comment: As [Christopher proposed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43789104/3773066), use `ListView.Groups`.  Suggested reading: ([1](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/853a6a/grouping-listview-items-dynamically/), [2](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/08/use-listview-groups-in-c/), and especially [3](http://www.kettic.com/winforms_ui/csharp_guide/listview_feature_grouping.shtml))

Comment: @OhBeWise: Thanks, the link you give in [2](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/08/use-listview-groups-in-c/) is the key. Also, this question has been marked as "primarily opinion-based" which is just wrong. ListView is clearly the component to use in this case, not DataGridView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I was you, I would instead try implementing this with a [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) control. Set up two columns in it corresponding to the last two columns of your DataGridView implementation (Item and Grower), and use the [Groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.groups(v=vs.110).aspx) property to set up actual groups for each of your entries under your first (Group) column. This should use your available space much more efficiently.